# Grouping/Summarising and summing a data-frame based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) created from a numpy array that looks like:

```
0.22    1
0.31    1
0.91    1
0.48    2
0.2     2
0.09    2
0.9     3
0.71    3
0.73    3
0.65    4
0.16    4
0.9     4
0.75    5
0.87    5
0.72    5
0.68    6
0.54    6
0.48    6
```

I want to create a summary data-frame that sums values in the first column relative to its position in the second column.  So my desired summary data-frame output from the above example would look like:

```
3.68    total
2.79    total
3.83    total
```

Where:
the first value in the summary data-frame would be equal to: `0.22+0.48+0.9+0.65+0.75+0.68=3.68`

the second value in the summary data-frame would be equal to: `0.31+0.2+0.71+0.16+0.87+0.54=2.79`

the third value in the summary data-frame would be equal to:
`0.91+0.09+0.73+0.9+0.72+0.48=3.83`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do groupby twice, one to label the relative position within each group, one to sum:

```
df[0].groupby(df.groupby(df[1]).cumcount()).sum()
```

Output:

```
0    3.68
1    2.79
2    3.83
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

**Option 2**: If all groups have equal number of elements, we can just reshape:

```
df[0].values.reshape(df[1].max(),-1).sum(0)
# out
# array([3.68, 2.79, 3.83])
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting a Key Error when I implement both of the above solutions :    File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 352, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 1

Comment: @Stacey replace `0` and `1` with your respective column names.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this the following pattern is often useful. To group by every n-th row, you can use `df.index % n` if your index is sorted and consecutive.

```
n = 3
df.groupby(df.index % n)[0].sum()
```

Output

```
0    3.68
1    2.79
2    3.83
```